# How to redirect to another function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, websocket

I am running web-socket on node js and sending the value from the node js to php codeigniter controller and after that I am trying to redirect to another function every time when the value is inserted. The data is inserting but the redirecting function not working can anyone help me solve this issue.

This is my controller function:

```php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$new_id = $this->Iot_lora_data_model->set($_POST);
redirect ('websocket/data_process/'.$new_id);
```

Comment: load url helper  `$this->load->helper('url');` and then you can redirect as `redirect('websocket/data_process/'.$new_id, 'refresh');`

Comment: It is already loaded and still not working

Comment: so print `$new_id` that you got `$new_id` or not .

Comment: I checked that and I am getting a value in the $new_id

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use
    header ('Location:InsertUriHere'');
And pass some your variable in the method.

Answer (score 0):

if redirect is not working, maybe you should check nothing is outputting some text before redirect, and also check other possible error factors as described in the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect). 
Other checks could be:

> When the location method is used, an HTTP status code of 303 will automatically be selected when the page is currently accessed via POST and HTTP/1.1 is used.

Also, there are two more parameters that you should check, like using `location` in your second param in order to avoid unwanted chooses.

> redirect ('websocket/data_process/'.$new_id, 'location');

And as a final solution, John Rhoy Gadot is right by suggesting the use of `header('location:'. base_url().''websocket/data_process/'.$new_id', true, "30X")`

Mind the `X` in `30X` and check the proper [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Redirection_messages).
And also check the [`header` function document](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) for the second parameter true by default.

Hope something of all this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :
header('Location: '.URL);